# Not getting a response from web service - not sure what I'm doing wrong

Tags: php, curl

This is my first shot at getting something back from a web service.  What I'm expecting is something to the effect of 'Authorization Failed'.  The URL is one in our test environment and the XML being sent is correct, but I'm not getting a response and don't know what I'm doing wrong.

The service is REST, the headers have to pass an encoded authorization (this example is correct) and the content type is set as xml.

When I use the same parameters to test it in the Advanced Rest Client in Chrome it connects and gives me a response.

Also, if there's a better way to create the XML, I'm all for that - this is just an example I found and started with.  Code is below

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_POST['firstname']))   {
?>

    <form name="ppost" method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
        <input type="text" name="firstname" />
        <input type="submit" name="SUbmit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
<?php

    } // end if, form not posted

    else {

        extract($_POST);

        $inputdata = '
        <ReqGetWebUserInfo>
        <OrgId>598</OrgId>
        <OrgUnitId>598</OrgUnitId>
        <MasterCustomerId>'.$firstname.'</MasterCustomerId>
        <SubCustomerId>0</SubCustomerId>
        </ReqGetWebUserInfo>';

        echo '<pre>'.$inputdata.'</pre>';

        $url = "https://gsusacustom.ebiz.uapps.net/GSUSARestWebService/PersonifyWcfSvc.svc/GetWebUserInfo";
        $headers = array(
                    'Authorization: Basic dG1hc2d1bmRhbTpwYXNzd29yZDE=',
                    'Content-Type: application/xml;charset=utf-8',
        );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );                   //  THE URL TO FETCH - CAN ALSO BE SET IN THE CURL_INIT
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);         
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);                    //  DON'T INLCUDE HEADER IN THE OUTPUT
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);                      //  TRUE FOR A REGULAR HTTP POST 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $inputdata);       //  THE DATA POST FROM THE FORM
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
        print $response;

    }                                                       // end else, form submitted and processed 

?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you didn't handle the `https` connection as your has it. Try this option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
```

If the error still persists then do the following to dig more.

Run the code with enabling all error reporting:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Run the curl with enabling debugging option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
```

Comment: That was it - I'll have to a lot more digging to understand a bit better but this works great.  Thanks so much.